# Не работает стиль Telerik.RadButton

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

Изначально кнопка была без стиля, и картинка и текст отображались корректно. На данную кнопку был прикреплён триггер. В результате чего картинка и текст были перенесены в стиль. А стиль не работает. Пробовал применить contentpresenter, но результата нет. Что я упустил?

```xml
<telerik:RadButton Command="{Binding CreateReportCommand}">
                    <telerik:RadButton.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadButton}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadButton}">
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <Image
                                            Width="16"
                                            Height="16"
                                            Source="{telerik:RadGlyph Glyph={StaticResource GlyphPlay},
                                                                      Foreground=MediumSeaGreen}" />
                                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                            <TextBlock
                                                Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                Text="Сформировать" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedScripts.Count}" Value="0">
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </telerik:RadButton.Style>
                </telerik:RadButton>
```

Comment: Разметка выглядит номрмально, так что вопрос скорее к разработчикам этой кнопки.

Comment: Стиль дописывал я, по этому мог не правильно его применить.